# Must I unpack a war file to run a single class?

Tags: java, war

I have a .war file that represents a complex web application. It works that way perfectly. But one of the classes in WEB-INF/classes also has a main() that is a small helper utility. We'd like to be able to run that utility from the command line. It seems to me there ought to be a way to form a classpath out of all of the jars in WEB-INF/lib inside the war, plus WEB-INF/classes.

It just seems to me like this is a problem that has to have been solved before.

Worst case, I can unpack the war into a temp directory, but I'd really rather not.

Comment: If you're using Maven, you can have the build process (with maven-jar-plugin) create a separate jar file containing only the utility class in addition to the full war file.

Comment: @azurefrog it does indeed look like a duplicate of that one. My search skills failed me first time.

Comment: We are using maven, but it would be nicer to avoid a separate artifact. Whether that's more ugly than unpacking the war into a temp dir though... :)

Comment: Isn't your application server unpacking the WAR File? Then you could run the class easily on the CLI.

Comment: The utility needs to be able to be run before the application server is started the first time.